# What backend platform is Opa running on?

Tags: node.js, opa

I wonder what backend platform Opa is using for communication with the browsers.

My guess would be Node.js.

Comment: As in Cedrics answer: no Node.js. In fact Opa is a complete solution with very minimal dependencies.

Answer (score 7):

Opa has his own application server. No extra application is needed.

We have our own scheduler handling both networks events and client computations (we use cooperative threads). We wrote a protocol specific language and built an http server with it.

Have a look at the compiler source code (check `appruntime/` and `libnet/` for scheduler and networks libs) :
https://github.com/MLstate/opalang

Answer (score 1):

Opa has switched its default backend platform to Node.js.